# ttyusb udev naming by hardware port

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, udev, usbserial

I Have two usb->serial adapters, both ftdi, lets name them ftdiA, and ftdiB. 
The device (in this case raspberry pi but it is kind of irrelevant) has 2 USB ports, let's name them 'top' and 'bottom'.

Is there a way to create udev rule so, that no matter which adapter is used in top port it gets name for example /dev/ttyUSBTop

I would like to name them based on the port where they were plugged in.
Even if there is a ftdiC adapter plugged in top port its name should be /dev/ttyUSBTop

Is it possible for xxxxA device that is not ftdi, but moschip, pl2013, or some other manufacturer that also creates /dev/ttyUSBX device, to get the same name based on connection -> /dev/ttuUSBTop or /dev/ttyUSBBottom?

I cant find similar request, all point to opposite requirement, they all want /dev/ttyUSBftdiA no matter where it is plugged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a rules file (`60-persistent-serial.rules`) that creates pretty paths in `/dev/serial/by-path/` that match the port. For example, when my USB serial device got inserted in a USB 3.0 port:

```
$ ls -l serial/by-path/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr  2 22:20 pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
```

And when the same device is connected to a different USB 2.0 port:

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial/by-path/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr  2 22:20 pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
```

Comment: I just checked, it seams to do what i want, 
I can also make links to these files so that filename looks more user friendly
I was close to the solution but i was in some other folder where names are like pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-port0, but one of numbers was incrementing when i pluged the port again

Comment: That increasing number was likely the Device ID which indeed increases every time the device gets (re-)enumerated.

Comment: it seams constant in this folder
anyway how do i accept this answer, i am new here and there are some reputation requirements??

Comment: The links in this folder will stay constant (unless you add another hub between the USB port and your device). To accept an answer, click the tick on the left of the answer below the voting buttons. See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/150311) for a picture.